# Template and typename syntax

Tags: c++, syntax, alias, template-meta-programming

I implemented the following `struct` to retrieve class member arguments:

```
template<typename...T>
class pack{};

template<typename...T>
struct getArgs{};
template<typename C,typename R,typename...Args>
struct getArgs<R(C::*)(Args...)>{using Type=pack<Args...>;};
```

But am unsure of the syntax to use it.

If I have a class `func1` defined as:

```
template<typename T>
struct func1{
    constexpr T operator()(T x){return x+1;}
};
```

I was hoping `typename getArgs<typename func1<int>::operator()>::Type` to be equivalent to `pack<int>` but my template argument keeps getting rejected as invalid.

So `typename getArgs<typename some_class<class_template_args>::member_function>::Type` 
doesn't appear to be the proper syntax. Any help? Thanks!

Edit: I would ideally like to not instantiate an object of the `func1` class and have had success doing so for other functions I've created...

E.g. `typename getN<1,pack<float,int> >::Type x;` works as `float x;`
where

```
template<std::size_t N,typename T,typename...Args>
struct getN_help:getN_help<N-1,Args...>{};
template<typename T,typename...Args>
struct getN_help<1,T,Args...>{using Type=T;};


template<std::size_t N,typename T>
struct getN;
template<std::size_t N,typename T,typename...Args>
struct getN<N,pack<T,Args...> >{
    using Type=pack<typename getN_help<N,T,Args...>::Type>;
};
```

Comment: `Args...` is the pack of types that the function accepts?

Comment: Ok, you have `func1<T>` whose `operator()` takes a single `T`.  Are you or are you not assuming that the template parameters to the callable are the same as the types the callable function accepts?

Comment: Yes, but I do not want to use that as a shortcut...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line:

```
getArgs<typename func1<int>::operator()>::Type
```

`typename func1<int>::operator()` is not a type, it's a function. You need to call `decltype()` on a pointer to it. Use `operator&` to get a pointer to member:

```
getArgs<decltype(&func1<int>::operator())>::Type
```

Comment: I now have another error: In `typename getArgs<decltype(&func1<int>::operator())>::Type y;` g++ complains that "Type" does not name a type.

Comment: @dumb0 [The code works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/19b189f8271c1a30). What does yours look like?

Comment: Definitely a compile failure:  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a21cfab5fe72b673/main.cpp            `test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:16:55: error: 'Type' in 'struct getArgs<int (func1<int>::*)(int)const>' does not name a type
  typename getArgs<decltype(&func1<int>::operator())>::Type z;`

Comment: @dumb0 That's weird. It works in Clang with `constexpr` but not with GCC.

Comment: I have the feeling GCC is (incorrectly) telling me that `Type` is a value. Maybe GCC is over-eagerly evaluating `operator()`. Should I file a bug report?

Comment: @dumb0 I'm not sure. You should ask about it.